# If $u$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for prime $p$, then $u^{p-1}=[1]$. Why?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

As part of a proof of Fermat's little theorem, my teacher used that if $u$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with $p=$ prime then $u^{p-1}=[1]$. Can someone help me understand why that statement is true?

Comment: Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: To anyone downvoting - can you please let me know what is wrong with my question?

Comment: What do you think the statement of Fermat's Little Theorem is?

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A very general way to see this is to observe that the units modulo $p$ define a (multiplicative) group with $p-1$ elements and use the fact that if $G$ is any group with $n$ elements then $g^n=e_G$ for every $g\in G$ (here $e_G$ denotes the identity element in $G$).

This general fact is a consequence of Lagrange's theorem: the number of elements in a subgroup divides the number of the elements of the group. Thus $g^d=e_G$ for some $d$ dividing $n$ (consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$), but then it is clear that $g^n=e_G$.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.